# Underworld Royalties

Tags: cipher, rebus, steganography, cryptic-clues

## 1. Mr. Edison's Travel Diaries

> From Liverpool, James Edison traveled to Valencia. After watching the scheduled match, he then traveled to Italia and then Amsterdam where he promised to return in the future to meet up with his friend. After settling some Visa issues, he then was on his flight to go to the beautiful city of Tripoli, the Capital of Libya. His next flight was to the city of Havana, in Cuba. From there, he went back for a short stoppage in Amsterdam to meet a friend. His final leg of the journey around the world was a rather long flight to New York. The summer had proved to be quite a long and pleasing one.

## 2. Maria's Prayer

> Clementissimus magnus
> Dominus immortalis
> Moderator magnus
> Creator auctor
> Creator

## 3. Devil with a heart

> Don’t ever win public (3)
> She’s being weird lately (5)
> The dress’s dollars(5)
> Thebe is of the Roman Empire(5)
> I, Chan taught Martial arts(5)

## 4. Easy Twists

> GUAVE(4,5) =
> FEHYT(3)    =
> DOYBIL(5,6) =
> AYNCOR(1,2) =

## 5. You miss something here

> Watching street gang (7)
> I point to an immoral act (3)
> Grin after destroying lies(5)
> The creator who provides money(7)
> Requirements are seen rising(5)
> European success following win (5)
> Flat tech field inside stack exchange(5)
> You and K? (8)

## 6. Just a Rebus. Nothing else.

[image][image][image]

**Your final answer should be a name. Bonus, if you can find a number related to that name.**

<sub>P.S. *I request you guys to avoid posting partial answers unless you have successfully solved at least 3 of the given mini-puzzles.*</sub>

Comment: Unusual spelling in #4. (Old rather than unusual, I suppose.)

Comment: ... Though the oldest thing I can find containing what I think is the right set spells it the other way.

Comment: (If the existing answer isn't yet complete enough to warrant Acceptance, a hint or two to help get it across the finish line might now be in order. Or, you might consider just supplying what little is left to solve as an edit to the answer, and then Accept.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1: Mr Edison's Travel Diaries**

> Pick out initial letters of destinations (taking the more specific when we have something like "Havana in Cuba"), including the E of "Edison" for reasons that aren't clear to me; we get **LEVIATHAN**.

**2: Maria's Prayer**

> This is enciphered, as MOehm noticed and I didn't, using Trithemius's "Ave Maria" cipher, which replaces letters with pious-sounding Latin words. It says **BEELZEBUB**.

**3: Devil with a heart**

> I think these are "printer's devilry" clues (full disclosure: Sid posted something about such clues in TSL chat recently). @jafe in comments made the excellent suggestion that the title is telling us to extract *middle letters* and suggested answers (matching my conjectured overall answer) to three of them: A**S**H (... wash in public) for the first, EN**A**CT (... been acting ...) for the second, and ST**A**RT (the best art ...) for the fourth. It seems clear that this is leading us to **SATAN**. (Uh-oh.) Bananenkopp suggests for the fifth that maybe we should insert SE**N**SE at the *beginning* of the clue to make "sensei"; that's unusual for a PD clue but seems plausible otherwise. The third is still mystifying. The obvious guess would be that it's something to do with the dress's d[..t. c]ollars but so far as I can tell there is no way to make that work. [EDITED to add, 2021-05:] I never figured out anything good for that slot and Sid said he'd forgotten what the intention was. In TSL chat, jafe proposed OFTEN ("the dress's of ten dollars", which doesn't sound like English to me but never mind) and Sid reckons that was in fact what he had in mind. Anyway, that gives us the required T and indeed Satan seems to be the devil needed here.

**4: Easy Twists**

> Anagram to get VAGUE, HEFTY, BODILY and CRAYON respectively, then pick out the letters whose positions are in parentheses (no, those are not enumerations!) to get **LUCYFER**.

**5: You miss something here**

> Each cryptic clue has wordplay leading to the answer *minus one letter*. We get ST(A)RING, (S)IN, S(M)ILE, F(O)UNDER, NEE(D)S, WHIT(E), S(U)ITE, THOU(S)AND so this is giving us **ASMODEUS**. (WHITE is due to MOehm; I had a much less plausible proposal. Not very keen on "European" as a definition of that word, though...)

**6: Just a Rebus. Nothing else**

> We have Judi Dench as "M" in James Bond; some AMMO; and the electron structure of NITROGEN. M/AMMO/N: we have **MAMMON**.

**Putting it together**

> These names look familiar! There is a somewhat-traditional list of seven principal devils ("Princes of Hell", hence the title), sometimes associated with the seven "deadly sins", and the solutions are six of the seven. We have Leviathan (envy), Beelzebub (gluttony), Satan (anger), Lucifer (pride), Asmodeus (lust), Mammon (greed). The missing one is **BELPHEGOR** (sloth). Aha, and his number will be 1000000000000066600000000000001, known as "Belphegor's Prime" for the rather inadequate reason that it contains 666 surrounded by 13 zeros on each side.

**Credit where due**

jafe found three answers in #3 and suggested the likely extraction mechanism there; Bananenkopp suggested another possible answer in #3. MOehm spotted what's going on in #2 and proposed a better solution than mine to the sixth clue in #5.

Comment: Nice work! I think the second one of #3 is rot13(ranpg).

Comment: That's plausible. (And it rules out the simplest possible extraction mechanism for #3, namely taking those numbers in order as indices, but e.g. we could do that and then anagram or something.)

Comment: (still not really here)

Comment: Note that the enumerations are all odd numbers and the title of the subsection is "...with a heart" :) A candidate for the first one could be rot13(nfu).

Comment: Also rot13(fgneg) for the fourth one, maybe.

Comment: Oh, you very clever person. I bet this is right. (Still not really here.)

Comment: Your answer for is correct. The code is [hinted at by the title](https://www.sciencefocus.com/science/10-of-the-most-mysterious-codes-and-ciphers-in-history/), see no.3; a useful table is [here](https://texperimentales.hypotheses.org/156).

Comment: Aargh! I did wonder whether those words themselves might be significant, and googled the _first line_. If I'd just chucked in the words themselves the relevant link would have been search result number 1. D'oh! Thanks @MOehm for being less stupid than I am.

Comment: Do you mean the first line of the code? I just did that and got the right results. So I'm really just more lucky than you are. (But I enjoy the rare moments where I can pass as less stupid than you, justified or not ...)

Comment: (For what it's worth, I think "European" just refers to a skin colour in the cryptic clue.)

Comment: Did you put quotation marks around the line? I did.

Comment: Stumbled across this... maybe for #3, Clue 5 rot13(Chg "Frafr" va sebag bs V, tvivat Frafrv Puna)

Comment: I guess. I don't think I've ever before seen a PD clue where the insertion is at one end rather than somewhere in the middle, but it works well enough.